# Cant write to iframe form

Tags: javascript, iframe

I try to write to the form fields inside a iframe from a JavaScript file. For this, i use the following code.

```
$(document).ready(                                                                                                                                                                         
    function()
    {                                                                                                                                                                                  
    var iframe = document.getElementById("iframeid");                                                                                                                     
    var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
    var input = innerDoc.getElementById('textinputfield');                                                                                                                                   
    input.value = "test";
    }
```

);

But now i get the error "TypeError: input is null" in Firefox. The content in the iframe is on the same domain (only a different folder), but it seems, that i cant write to the form fields. After filling in the value, i would like to submit the form.

What can i do?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle and/or a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Does different folder also mean different sub-domain? The same origin policy considers different port and different sub-domain as different origin also

Answer (score 0):

Have found the problem... if i use $(document).ready(  the context is the calling script, not the iframe. In this case this means, that the calling script is loaded, but not the content of the iframe. I have added now a onloadhandler to the iframe tag and in the handler i could write to the fields.